# Mule 4 - concatenating payload with some attributes

Tags: mule4

New to Mule4 and playing around. I have a setPayload transformer and under setting
I am adding the following

```
#[payload ++ " " ++  message.attributes.queryParams.lname]
```

However I am getting the following error. What is the right way of doing this?

Scripting language error on expression 'payload ++ " " ++  message.attributes.queryParams.lname'. Reason: Unable to call any overload of function `++` with arguments (String, String | Null) overloads:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot concatenate String **(i.e. "Hello")** with null **( i.e. attributes.queryParams.lname could be null)**. So in this case, you will have to set a default value to the right-hand side expression. try below script -->

```
"Hello" ++  (attributes.queryParams.lname default "")
```